# How do you find the origin of an event? [VueJS]

Tags: javascript, vue.js, web

In Vue3, I am trying to see the source of my event.
We are using Bootstrap-vue, and so far we have managed to see if an event comes from an input field with `event.target.__vue__.$parent.$options._componentTag`.

However, this is not possible with a `<b-form-radio-group>` as it has no `_componentTag`.

So my question is, how do you see the button which fired/origin of an event?

Comment: Have you tried without `$parent` ?

Comment: It does not work as it breaks and gives `Cannot read property '$parent' of undefined` . All of the fired events have different properties, for some reason.

Is there no easy or general way to fetch the origin of an event?

Comment: There is no easy way. If you receive `Cannot read property "xxx" of undefined` - it means that the thing on the left of `.$parent` evaluates to `undefined` and this obviously is not what I suggested. My suggestion was to use `event.target.__vue__.$options._componentTag`

Comment: I am looking or this too? `$options._componentTag` is undefined in Vue3. 
You could use 
```
    const match = this.$options.__file.match(/([^/\\]+)\.\w+$/);
    if (match) {
      return match[1];
    }
``` 
But `__file` is not available in a production built. Have you found a solution?

Comment: We ended up adding a tag to each component that we want to ignore - an example:
<b-input
                  id="filterText"
                  data-ignore-change
                />
Then, we could filter on the events that had this tag with:

if (!event.target.hasAttribute("data-ignore-change")) {
        this.setUnsavedChanges(true);
      }

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up adding a tag to each component that we want to ignore - an example:

```
<b-input id="filterText" data-ignore-change />
```

Then, we could filter on the events that had this tag with:

```
if (!event.target.hasAttribute("data-ignore-change")) { 
   this.setUnsavedChanges(true); 
}
```

Hope this helps!